# Inserting with MySQL while in a scheduled task?

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line-interface

I am running MySQL on Windows 7. I use a scheduled task to insert a record into a table after an action has occurred. However, when the scheduled task runs, nothing is inserted. I have redirected output from the "mysql" line into a log file, but the log is always empty. Running the batch file manually does cause the record to be inserted successfully. The scheduled task runs under the same user account and priveleges as when I run it manually.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  Apparently despite being run as my account, "taskeng" doesn't know where "mysql" is.  Writing the full path to the mysql executable solved it.

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, please mark your answer as accepted so that others can learn from your solution.  Cheers~